# error handling/propagation in spring integration

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-integration

I've read that if exception is thrown in the flow the first thing the framework will do is check message header for error-channel property. Is it always the case?

In my particular case I'm assigning a custom error-channel to a message header and yet the message seems to get propagated up the stream to the nearest error-handler/error-channel.

```
<int:chain id="buildAggregatedResponseChain" input-channel="aggregatedResultChannel"
               output-channel="sendAggregatedChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:error-channel ref="myErrorChannel"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:service-activator ref="service" method="doSomething"/>
    </int:chain>
```

I explicitly throw an exception inside doSomething but the exception never ends up in myErrorChannel. Instead, it is "propagated" to the nearest ErrorHandler up the stream or to the error-channel specified up the stream for int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter(tried several different flows).
 What do I miss? Maybe someone can outline the main principal of error handling/error propagation(for example when talking about several transactions, etc)? There is some information out there, but it is quite scattered and not systematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the upstream flow; if there's an async handoff the header is consulted; otherwise, the exception is thrown back to the inbound endpoint.

In general, I would advise against modifying framework headers such as `errorChannel`. Instead put an `error-channel` on the inbound endpoint (such as your imap idle adapter) and handle the errors on that flow.

Modifying the headers directly is rarely needed. If you wish to insert different error-handling mid-flow then you can insert a messaging gateway...

```
<int:service activator ... ref="gw" />

<int:gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="..." 
    error-channel="midFlowErrorChannel" />
```

If the downstream flow (from the gateway) returns no result on success, then be sure to add a default reply timeout of 0 (or use a custom service interface with a method that returns void).

Comment: "If you wish to insert different error-handling mid-flow then you can insert a messaging gateway" - that what I would ask about next:)